# Configuring Texmaker for Tex Live

Tags: packages, texlive, texmaker, ubuntu

On my Ubuntu machine, I have just downloaded Texmaker and Tex Live. I now want to compile a Latex file which uses the `tcolorbox` package. From what I have read, this package should come with Tex Live (the documentatoin says `Typically, tcolorbox will be installed as part of a major LATEX distribution and there is nothing special to do for a user`).

So, I want to tell Texmaker to use Tex Live. To do this, I went into the Texmaker configuration, and set the Latex and PdfLatex executables to be those from Tex Live; see the picture below:

[image]

However, this did not work for me. When compiling the file in Texmaker using `PdfLatex`, I get the error message: `! LaTeX Error: Environment tcolorbox undefined`.

So, does this mean that Tex Live definitely does not come with `tcolorbox`? If so, how can I install `tcolorbox`?

Alternatively, perhaps I am not configuring Texmaker correctly to use Tex Live. If so, how else should I be doing it?

Comment: Did you use the full install of TeXLive? Does your document compile on console?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I installed the full version of Tex Live. Running `pdflatex` (the version that comes with Tex Live) on my file from the console gives me the same error message... How can I check whether the package is definitely installed?

Comment: Try `kpsewhich tcolorbox.sty` on the console

Comment: If you Linux is setup correctly you do not need to specify full path to latex, just writing pdflatex is enough . So what exactly did you install, Ubuntu tex live or upstream tex live. Ubuntu texlive is split into many smaller parts, whereas upstream tex live is a single unit (in a default installation) that includes everything available for texlive users.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich article.cls` on the command line give you, and also the result of `which pdflatex `

Comment: @daleif I installed upstread Tex Live, following the instructions here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: @daleif `kpsewhich article.cls` prints out `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`

Comment: @daleif `which pdflatex` prints out `/usr/bin/pdflatex` .... Maybe this is the problem, as it is not using the Tex Live version?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `kpsewhich tcolorbox.sty` prints out `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
`

Comment: @Karnivaurus: Have you told `TeXlive` to make the symlinks during the installation?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware....

Comment: I've managed to get `which pdflatex` to return `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`, however, this is still not letting me compile from the command line, using `pdflatex myfile.tex`

Comment: You seem to have two latex installations, exactly how did you add upstream texlive to your PATH?

Comment: @daleif I added the following line to my `.bashrc` file:
`export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`

Comment: What do you mean by "it will not let me compile from the command line", exactly what happens?

Comment: Changing the path in dot-bashrc is asking for trouble, then texmaker can only see the latex installation if texmaker is started from the command line. It will pickup the wrong texlive if started from a menu or by double clicking a tex file. More that line to dot-profile, log out and in again.

Comment: Sorry, that was an ambiguous comment. What I mean, is that if I try to compile from the command line, I still get the error: `! LaTeX Error: Environment tcolorbox undefined`.

Comment: Bashrc is only used in a bash context, the shell texmaker is using is more prioritize thus bashrc is never executed by that shell, it will just use what ever is already there.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However, if I run `which pdflatex` then I get `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`. Furthermore, as in the diagram in my original question, I am explicitly telling Texmaker to use Tex Live's pdflatex

Comment: Exactly which upstream texlive did you install? Full or minimal?

Comment: Again please run `kpsewhich tcolorbox.sty` and `kpsewhich article.cls ` on the command line and report

Comment: I installed the full version. This includes a file at: `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty`. But it is `tcolorbox` which it is telling me it cannot find.

Comment: `kpsewhich tcolorbox.sty` returns with `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty`. And `kpsewhich article.cls` returns with `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`.

Comment: And there exists a file at `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty`

Comment: So it is found. If your compilation still gives you an error about tcolorbox, then please post the tex file. The package is on your computer